# Available Online Recordings for Acoustic Echo Identifiablity

Tags: audio, reference-request, deconvolution

I am trying to add a few samples for a publication on identification of clean signal from the one which has echo on it. For this purpose I need data set that includes playback of an already available signal in a big room/hall and the recording of the signal with a mic in this hall that includes the echo.

Does anybody know of any available online source for such data samples.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any online recordings, but you could try using the [Silophone player](http://www.silophone.net/eng/play/index.html) to create some.  Play your original file, then record what the silophone plays back.
[Silophone homepage](http://www.silophone.net/)

The Silophone uses an old grain silo as an echo chamber.  It also plays the echoed audio locally over a speaker outside the silo, so you might want to avoid using anything obnoxious or private or copyrighted.